# Open database for JEL code crawling (using article names)

Tags: data-request, api, research, python

I'm currently working on a project to create a database (for analysis later on) of 100 journals, and all the articles for these journals between 1969 and 2014. This of course results in over half a million articles. The most important parameters i need for these articles is the [JEL code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEL_classification_codes) and the date(year) of publication. So far I have created a list of journals and used the crossref API to get an approximation of the number and names of articles they include.

Example is for the journal "Econometrica", the API query: http://search.crossref.org/?q=Econometrica&type=Journal+Article Returns 6200+ articles, each of them with full name and a DOI link. The problem is the DOI link does not always include the general information, however they often include the pdf version of the article, which in term of data crawling is not really efficient to scan through 500.000 articles for JEL code.

I was wondering if you know another database/API that might return the JEL and publication date by using the article name as query?

Comment: Try https://ideas.repec.org/getdata.html . You'll need to download their dataset, parse `(article, jel)` pairs & then search it locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try Transpose.com. It uses a drag and drop platform with a bunch of different fields so you can create the exact database you need. It also uses search analytics so you find anything you've input by just typing it in.

Comment: transpose looks like a paid option....thats not open so unless you can clarify that its not, i'm going to have to recommend this for closing